# How to enumerate over nested enumerators

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I have a variable `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`. I'm trying to somehow aggregate it into an `IEnumerable<int>` which enumerates over all the integers in order. (All the integers from the first set, then all the integers from the second, etc.) I looked into LINQ's aggregate method, but the only examples I found was string concatenation, and I can't figure out how to apply it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `SelectMany` which can be used to flatten nested `IEnumerable<T>` structures into an unnested `IEnumerable<T>`

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> enumerable;
IEnumerable<int> flat = enumerable.SelectMany(x => x);
```